# PHP : What is the best way to fetch string coming between some palceholder

Tags: php

I wondering if somebody can help me

I have this code for getting some text between [reply]

```
$msg    =   '> **
>   <#1371620c479a4e98_>  Chauffeure -Emails  driver_age:72
> driver_nationality:IN
> driver_languages:French,
> driver_name:Rinto George
> driver_mobilenumber:9747 161861
> driver_email:rinto@example.com[reply]I am a principal yes , I know
> you[reply]  Fragen oder Hilfe benotigt?
> 089-38168530 Secure Transmission of Sensitive Data by SSL
>';
```

**Used Code**

```
preg_match_all("/\[reply](.*)\[reply]/", $msg, $reply); 
print_r($reply)
```

But it doesn't outputs my desired output

**Suggestion**

If you could sort it out by using [reply]Reply here[/reply] would be better,as I am using [reply][reply] , not looking well formed

Comment: Do you want a function which will give you "I am a principal yes , I know you" from the above string?

Comment: the only thing you need is an `s` modifier and a ? greedy modifier. not a big deal. See Gokhan's answer, it is correct

Comment: you may also wish to use preg_split() if you want to get both replies and texts between

Comment: @duke I have posted another solution under my own that does [reply] [/reply] as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want regex. While you can accomplish what you're trying to do for the most basic cases with a simple regex like the one webbandit posted, it's going to break on more complicated examples (like the one in my comment).

That can be worked around with a better regex and lookaheads, but that's not what you want. You're doing string matching and you should be using a finite machine to pull this off. PHP's string algorithms can give you something quick and dirty that would work much better, e.g.

```
<?php

$text = "[reply] something [reply] bla bla bla [reply] something else [reply]";

$matches = array();
$lastMatch = 0;
$matchCount = 0;

$search = "[reply]";

while(true) {
    $thisMatch = strpos($text, $search, $lastMatch+1);
    if($thisMatch === FALSE)
        break;
    if(++$matchCount % 2 == 0)
    {
        $lastMatch = $thisMatch;
        continue;
    }
    //print substr($text, $lastMatch + strlen($search), $thisMatch - $lastMatch - strlen($search)) . "\n";
    array_push($matches, substr($text, $lastMatch + strlen($search), $thisMatch - $lastMatch - strlen($search)));
    $lastMatch = $thisMatch;
}

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Will give you an array of replies in `$matches`.

Output:

```
[mqudsi@iqudsi:~/Desktop]$ php reply.php 
Array
(
    [0] =>  something 
    [1] =>  something else 
)
```

---

For your revised question with `[reply]` and `[/reply]`, the solution is here:

```
$text = "[reply] something [/reply] bla bla bla [reply] something else [/reply]";

$matches = array();
$end = -1;

while(true) {
    $start = strpos($text, "[reply]", $end+1);
    $end = strpos($text, "[/reply]", $start+1);
    if($start === FALSE || $end === FALSE)
        break;

    array_push($matches, substr($text, $start + strlen("[reply]"), $end - $start - strlen("[reply]")));
    $lastMatch = $thisMatch;
}
```

Comment: It will not work , gives me Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted and lot of other errors while(true) {

Comment: OMG, "you don't need no regex". Yeah, you need a pageful of code instead

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you want to do it the right way that won't break for every input you didn't think of, that is. And if you don't want your process to take half an hour and a shitload of RAM.

Comment: This is merely a false statement. As a matter of fact, you can mistake input data and write wrong code with this pageful of string functions as well.

Comment: @GokhanOzturk the compiler doesn't run your loops. And loops don't halt because they're long, only recursion could do that with a stack overflow exception. I'll bet the loop (with a few obvious fixes) runs faster and with less memory than the regex in your answer for code with 200 replies. My code doesn't read the string from the start each time.

Answer (score 0):

Take odd array result of regex filter `/\[reply\].*/` will give you what you want

here the result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [reply]I am a principal yes , I know
            [1] => [reply]  Fragen oder Hilfe benotigt?
        )

)
```

Comment: No it won't. Regex is greedy by default. It'll eat up as much as it can with `(.*)`, including other `[reply]` strings.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno why Gokhan deleted his answer, but it was the right one.

```
"~\[reply](.*?)\[/reply]~is"
```

The only two things you need is an `s` modifier which tells regexp to apply expression to the whole text, not each string separately (as it is by default)
and a greed limiter `?`

Comment: He deleted it when I pointed out that it was wrong until you fixed it. Your answer is correct and far simpler than mine. If the bbcode parsing is not a performance-sensitive operation, this is a good answer. If memory or performance do matter, then it would be time to sacrifice clarity and conciseness for a state machine like the one in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Regex is: `/\[reply\]([^\[]+)\[\/reply\]/g`

Comment: Not really. That would break here: `[reply]bla bla [ha ha] bla bla[reply]`. Using regex for this is a bad idea.

Comment: Look modified answe. Like in suggestion.